# Как обеспечить нормальную сортировку для папок

Tags: файлы, сортировка

Предположим, есть главы с 1 по 8. Чуть позже автор добавляет условный бонус 7.5.

Теперь, я хочу делать довольно однообразное именование глав, изначальная идея "Глава 0001" к примеру. Стабильно работает (пока глав меньше 10к, да) сортировка, пока не появляются бонусные главы.

Есть у кого хорошие идеи, как можно именовать главы, чтобы бонусы (особенно добавленные задним числом), не ломали сортировку и не попадали в самый конец или куда то в середину?

ПС: особенно добавляет удовольствия то, что точка в имени сортируется по разному на `win`/`unix`/`android` и в различных приложениях на этих ОС.

[image]

Comment: значит определить систему преобразования красивых номеров 7.5 в сортируемый формат. например определится что у нас максимум 3 уровня, т.е. может быть еще 7.5.1 и сделать нумерацию вида 0001000000, 0007005001

Comment: @Mike читабельность сильно падает. Я тогда уж подумываю про условные "0007.5 Глава о том как...", ведущие цифры вроде как обеспечат нужный порядок.

Comment: ну тогда на подверсии все таки места то же больше отводите 0007.005

Comment: @Mike спорный вопрос. Это 1 и 10 надо отличать явно, поэтому ведущие нули вынужден добавлять. В то время как .5 и .05 принципиально разные вещи и отсортируются по разному.

Comment: А, ну если вы точку рассматриваете как десятичную, а не как разделитель части версии то конечно нет смысла делать ведущие нули у второй части

Comment: @Mike Идея с трехуровневой версией интересная, но я в целом их раскладываю на уровни, в папке подпапки и так далее. Просто некоторые авторы умеют в такие вот неудобные бонусы,поэтому приходится извращаться.

Comment: @Mike, хм, но всё равно остается проблема с целыми и дробными. Как минимум 0007.5 раньше 0007 в linux mint считается. Делать заранее всех дробными? Тогда 0007.0 смотрится глуповато T_T

Comment: ну и, тогда можно цифры оставить после префикса типа "глава", ибо всяко херня =_+

Comment: Подскажите, есть ли у вас возможность хранить дополнительную информацию где бы то ни было: в оперативе, на диске? Правильно ли я понимаю, что все главы именуются в одинаковом стиле и отклонений быть не может?

Comment: @hedgehogues информацию хранить можно. Главы именуются в одном стиле исключительно для удобства сортировки ну и удобочитаемости.

Comment: Могут ли быть ситуации следующего характера: Добавили главу 7.5. Добавили главу 7.6. Хочется втиснуть между ними главу. Нужно ли это предусматривать?

Comment: @hedgehogues в теории - ситуация может быть. Но и одного знака после запятой мне в целом хватило бы.

Comment: Переименовывать не удобно при изменениях с списке?

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan неудобно. Во первых, может использоваться какая то читалка, у которой собственная индексация (и она пропустит или вынудит перечитать наоборот главу), во вторых - I\O операции и так не особо стабильны, то права, то занято, то ещё что-нибудь.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Когда-то подобная проблема была и в бейсике, в котором нужно было нумеровать строки. И там было простое правило - строки нумеровать десятками. И если нужно вставить строку-две, проблемы не возникает. Подобная система перекочевала и в линуксовские конфиги. Поэтому, главы нумеруем десятками (или сотнями даже), добавляя в начале нужное кол-во нулей. Если нужно вставить главу по середине - проблемы нет. Пример имен файлов.

```
0010-1-chapter
0020-2-chapter
0030-3-chapter
0040-4-chapter
0050-5-chapter
0060-6-chapter
0070-7-chapter
0075-7-bonus
0080-8-chapter
```

Этот способ хорош тем, что если даже нужно будет вставить "интро", то просто нумеруем с `0000-...`, `0005-....`.

Зачем нужны нули в начале? В таком случае сортироваться будет везде одинаково. Проводник умеет понимать и без нулей, а другие заменители - не факт. Количество начальных нулей выбирается исходя с предполагаемого кол-ва глав.

Почему без точки? А точка не несет дополнительной информации. А вот разделитель нумерации и просто имени - нужен. Он упростит регулярки и другую рутину.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что в таком варианте я папку могу называть с комбинацией "0010-chapter", а цифра между ними - это для файлов?

Comment: Цифры в середине - это номер главы. А число в начале не обязательно совпадает с номером главы. Это для правильной сортировки.

Comment: Способ хороший, но мне не очень нравится неочевидное число в начале...

Comment: Хм, отдельный индекс в начале - забавная идея. И пока похоже самая живая.

Comment: Дайте пример конфига, который перекочевал в линукс с такой проблемой

Comment: не конфиг перекочевал, а идея.  Поищите в любом дистрибутиве где то так `find /etc/ -regex ".*/[0-9].*"`. И обнаружите, что им пользуются X11, php, apt, grub и другие. И главная задача, которую они решают - разбить конфиг на мелкие кусочки и потом включить их в правильном порядке в большой.

Answer (score 3):

А почему просто точка не подходит?

вариант 1, 2, 3.1, 3.2, 3.2.4, 3.2.5, 4, 5, ...

сортируютется и на Unix, и на Windows, и на Android одинаково

Если глав больше 10, 100, 1000, то нужно только первые нули добавить.

Точка при этом сортируется одинаково везде (проверил на Android, Win 7, CentOS, Linux)

Comment: Даже если с точкой что-то не так, можно её заменить на подчёркивание.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CzuR.png - глава 3 сломалась на таком отображении. Если без ведущих нулей - умудрились поломаться читалки на андроиде, как они сортируют - не в курсе.

Comment: @Qwertiy подчеркивание ничего не меняет, глава 3 всё так же идёт после главы 3_1

Answer (score 3):

Что тут важно:

1. Лексикографическая сортировка совпадает с желаемой.
2. Сортировка с учётом целых чисел совпадает с лексикографической. Для этого нужны лидирующие нули, приводящие все числа к одинаковой длине.
3. В качестве разделителя используется не точка, чтобы предотвратить сортировку с учётом дробных чисел, либо сортировка с учётом дробных чисел совпадает с лексикографической. Т. е. надо использовать одинаковое число знаков в дробной части.
4. Ни одно название не заканчивается сразу после номера. Там должен стоять символ, который гарантированно меньше разделителя. На эту роль подходит пробел.
5. Название не заканчивается и не начинается с точки или пробела. Поскольку в конце они не поддерживаются в виндоусе, в начале точка означает скрытость в линуксе, а пробел в начале местами сортируется неожиданным образом.

Поэтому можно не писать слово `Глава` в начале. И надо добавить название самой главы в конец через пробел. В таком случае пробел будет раньше чем точка или подчёркивание и всё встанет в нужном порядке.

```
0001 Какая-то первая глава
0002 Ну да, вторая
0003 А может трилогия
0003.50 Да, я умею вставлять в середину
0003.75 И не только в середину
0004 Неожиданное продолжение
```

Как оказалось, у Linux Mint какие-то свои представления о сортировке числовых значений, пробелов, точек и знаков пунктуации. Чтобы побороть их и свести сортировку к лексикографической, пришлось:

1. Добавить точку в конец номера главы.
2. Использовать точку с запятой в качестве разделителя.

Получается такой формат:

```
001. Какая-то папка
002. Ну и ещё что-то тут
002;5. Половинная
002;7. Ещё одна
003. Тетья на месте
004. И четвёртая - последняя
```

С этим форматом согласен проводник:

[image: скриншот проводника]

но, к сожалению, не консоль:

[image: скриншот консоли]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVbnU.png - может я чего не так сделал? цифра, пробел, текст. Порядок очевидно не тот.

Comment: @Monk, что за линукс?? У меня в минте таких проблем не было, кажется. Потом проверю. А если ещё одну точку добавить? `0003. А может трилогия`

Comment: mint, проводник Nemo 3.4.7. Добавление точки не помогает. Вот если 0003.0, то хорошо, но тогда можно точку вроде просто опустить =)

Comment: Попозже проверю. У меня минт есть. Единственная странность, которую замечал - что он не поднимает в начало имена, начинающиеся с пробела.

Comment: Как ни странно, но кроме минта всё что смог проверить - ведёт себя правильно в такой нумерации.

Comment: Судя по всему, для `ls` и линуксов в целом вполне нормально игнорировать пробел при сортировке. Нашли какое то простое решение? Вариант в целом рабочий, приложения в основном читают корректно.

Comment: @Monk, нашёл, что дефис ставится после точки `2. Smth`, `2-1. Smth`, но только после перезагрузки в винду дошло, что дефис-то лексикографически раньше))

Comment: @Monk, ну что-то получилось...

Comment: Не имею понятия, как некоторый софт сортирует, но некоторые читалки нормально работают со вторым вариантом, некоторые - наворачиваются и снова получается барахло =)

Answer (score 1):

0001.a whatever

0002.a more stuff

0003.a

0004.a wow

бонусы добавляют после .a:

0002.a.1 superbonus
0002.a.2 nothing

Answer (score -1):

Распарсить все названия, извлечь из них все номера в отдельную структурку/столбец или что там у тебя. Быть может быть несколько раз. Затем отсортировать по основному принципу, затем по этим дополнительным столбцам.

Примерно такое реализовано в проводнике Вин7. Сначала нравится, потом жутко бесит.

Comment: Так за сортировку я не отвечаю, мне как раз нужен механизм именования папок, чтобы его везде однообразно сортировало. Или я неправильно понял ответ?

Comment: У него файловая система. Чего куда извлекаем?

Comment: @Qwertiy, извлекаем номера из имен файлов. Каждую директорию читаем и извлекаем имена. Извлекаем в память, можно в какую-то базу засунуть чтобы быстрее было, но как выяснилось, автору это надо не это, а что-то еще.

Comment: У него есть просто папка с подпапками, которая каким-то образом синхронизируется с различными устройствами. Надо чтобы на всех этих устройствах порядок отображения подпапок был одинаковым и совпадал с логической последовательностью глав. Причём, должна быть возможность доложить главу в середину списка без переименования всех остальных. Соответственно вопрос - как надо назвать подпапки, чтобы это выполнялось.

Comment: Надо бы еще понять, откуда эти папки (и мамки) берутся вообще, какого их происхождение и как часто оно обновляется. Потому что мы решаем какую-то частную задачу, а надо ли автору разгрести какие-то авгиевы конюшни (вроде гигантских раздач книг), или он делает систему для издателей - непонятно. И в зависимости от того что мы делаем, можно уже искать дальше, причем ответ на этот вопрос хотелось бы увидеть непосредственно от автора, так как возможно вы тоже поняли что-то не так, равно как и я сам

Comment: да вроде всё верно описал Qwertiy, нужно чтобы разные ОС и приложения сортировали логично и одинаково папки по имени. Формат имени и читаемый и сортируемый пытаюсь найти.

Comment: А откуда оно берется, как много, как часто обновляется? Повторяю, это какая-то частная задача, а не видя общего решения остается только гадать и предлагать именовать все как в бейсике.

Comment: А какая разница откуда берется и как часто обновляется? Суть в том, что оно возникает хоть иногда и ручное разрешение таких ситуаций неудобно.

Comment: Разница очень большая. Если это потом раздается на торрентах, то имена файлов должны быть персистентны и их изменения не допустимы, а если это отдельный архив - в принципе можно переименовывать файлы и директории и это нормально. Если это как-то обновляется автоматически, то нам нужен какой-то контроллер коллизий, а если руками -  оператор всегда найдет место куда вставить новый файл. Не, если хотите решение для своей частной задачи - тут уже много разных предложили, мне больше всего вариант с Бейсиком понравился, а лично я за этим вижу какой-то бОльший процесс, но я не могу помочь с ним.